# Is there a way to undo a migration?

Tags: support, migration

"This question [Estimating the most abundant isotopomer of an isotopic distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4728487/estimating-the-most-abundant-isotopomer-of-an-isotopic-distribution) was migrated to Cross Validated because it can be answered by people interested in statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, and data visualization."

I'm not interested in any of those topics, yet I managed to write an answer to that question that was accepted by OP. I could do that because it was, in my opinion anyway, purely a math question, not a question about statistics, machine learning, etc., and I am interested in mathematics.

Is there any mechanism for "unmigrating" a question?

Comment: If a question is closed on the target site, it will be sent back to the original site.